# Why are nested macros needed?

Tags: c

In the following piece of code in the functional mock-up interface header file

```
#define fmiPaste(a,b)     a ## b
#define fmiPasteB(a,b)    fmiPaste(a,b)
#define fmiFullName(name) fmiPasteB(MODEL_IDENTIFIER, name)
```

Why are nested macros being used in the first place? Why not just

```
#define fmiPasteB(a,b)    a ## b
#define fmiFullName(name) fmiPasteB(MODEL_IDENTIFIER, name)
```

?

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with how `C` expands macros.

If you do not have the nested macro, then the literal symbol that is passed into `fmiFullName` will be stringified and used for concatenation, instead the expansion of the symbol.

Consider the sample program below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MODEL_IDENTIFIER Prefix

#define fmiPaste(a,b)     a ## b
#define fmiPasteB(a,b)    fmiPaste(a,b)
#define fmiFullName(name) fmiPasteB(MODEL_IDENTIFIER, name)


int main(){
    int Prefix1 = 2;
    int Prefix2 = 3;
    printf("%d\n", fmiFullName(1));
    printf("%d\n", fmiFullName(2));


#undef fmiPasteB
#undef fmiFullName


#define fmiPasteB(a,b)    a ## b
#define fmiFullName(name) fmiPasteB(MODEL_IDENTIFIER, name)

    int MODEL_IDENTIFIER1 = 100;
    int MODEL_IDENTIFIER2 = 1000;
    printf("%d\n", fmiFullName(1));
    printf("%d\n", fmiFullName(2));
}
```

Output:

```
int MODEL_IDENTIFIER1 = 100;
int MODEL_IDENTIFIER2 = 1000;
printf("%d\n", fmiFullName(1));
printf("%d\n", fmiFullName(2));
```